# Hosting multiple net core apps single server automation

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, automation

We have multiple apps running on Ubuntu under Nginx.

Standard config as follows:

```
   location /prod {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
...
    }
```

Above is copied and pasted for each app and all is good.

I have been researching a way to automate the port assignment so it can happen automatically during deployment.

The only way we can come up with is to have something check which ports are in use and assign the next on, create a config file on the fly for nginx and also create the .service file on the fly all at deployment time.

Is there any tools available to automate this as we have not found any or maybe we are searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: How would the proxy discover the random port assignments? Also consider YARP if you want to write C# logic in your proxy https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/getting-started.html

Comment: Can it be extended to use such dynamic Discovery?

Comment: Sure, check out the docs.